# What are the ways to create draw data structures for latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tikz, pgf

I tried tikz/pgf a bit but have not had much luck creating a nice diagram to visualize bitfields or byte fields of packed data structures (i.e. in memory). Essentially I want a set of rectangles representing ranges of bits with labels inside, and offsets along the top. There should be multiple rows for each word of the data structure. This is similar to most of the diagrams in most processor manuals labeling opcode encoding etc.

Has anyone else tried to do this using latex or is there a package for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully used the [`bytefield`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) package for something like this. If it doesn't do exactly what you want, please extend your question with an example...

Answer (score 1):

You will find several examples with both tikz code source and a visual rendering of this code at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/